How can I resolve access issues I'm having due to warnings in middleware.ts when trying to access my website?
I have a project using Next.js and I deployed it with Vercel. However, when I added the project domain to Google Search Console, it gave me a blocked for unauthorized request (401) error. When I looked at the Logs section in Vercel, it gave the warnings in the following codes. It said that this error was due to the Middleware file, but when I looked at the Middleware, I couldn't understand where I was doing wrong.This middleware file contains clerk and next-intl middleware. What is the problem?
Here is my middleware.ts file:
import { authMiddleware } from '@clerk/nextjs'
import createMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware'

const intlMiddleware = createMiddleware({
  locales: ['en', 'tr'],
  defaultLocale: 'tr',
})

export default authMiddleware({
  beforeAuth(req) {
    return intlMiddleware(req)
  },

  publicRoutes: ["/:locale", "/:locale/versions", "/:locale/:path*"], 
})

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/', '/(tr|en)/:path*', "/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};

Some warnings that appear in the Log in Vercel:
[GET] [middleware: "src/middleware"] /en status=401

[HEAD] [middleware: "src/middleware"] /en status=401

[FLURP] [middleware: "src/middleware"] / status=405

[CONNECT] [middleware: "src/middleware"] / status=405

I searched on stackoverflow and various sites, but I could not find the source of the problem.
